# Construction of a drift curve in the well tie calibration and how to interpret it?. Sonic calibration vs checkshot calibration

Tags: geophysics

Good afternoon. Inside the creation of the synthetic seismogram some softwares have the option to run what is called "sonic calibration" or "checkshot calibration". I have some questions:

1)why some softwares consider that the sonic should be calibrated while others consider the checkshot should be calibrated?

2)what is the interpretation of a positive drift curve and a negative drift curve?

3)According to my research, in order to apply drift correction, you should apply a smoothing to the drift curve. In the case of the softwares that apply checkshot calibration, the idea is to use the sonic data points to infill the checkshot. Also you have 3 curves in one log track:the original sonic log, the original checkshot and the calibrated checkshot. You then have another track with two drift curves: a fixed one, that represent the difference, in time value,between the original  checkshot and the original sonic log a a movable drift curve. In this curve,if apply a lot of smoothing, the corrected checkshot curve will be more similar to the original sonic curve. If you apply a small smoothing, the calibrated checkshot curve will be more similar to the original checkshot curve.

Is the idea that the calibrated curve to make it more similar to the original sonic curve, the original checkshot curve or something in between?why?

4)Similar to question 3, how does this apply in case you do a sonic calibration?

5)Are there big consequences of not doing checkshot/sonic calibration?which ones?

Comment: You can find your answer in this paper: Seismic versus sonic velocities: A vertical seismic profiling study

Comment: @BoonEeJuan *If* it is the paper you refer to, it would be easier for the OP to retrieve it with a link [like this one](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/274443386_Seismic_versus_sonic_velocities_A_vertical_seismic_profiling_study) which leads e.g., to [doi 10.1190/1.1441745](http://dx.doi.org/10.1190/1.1441745).

Comment: This is the paper GEOPHYSICS Volume 49, Issue 8
Seismic versus sonic velocities: A vertical seismic profiling study
Authors: Robert R. Stewart, Phil D. Huddleston and Tze Kong Kan
https://doi.org/10.1190/1.1441745